# Explicit casting problems, C

Tags: c, casting, unsigned, signed

I have this case statement in C:

```
case GOTO: {
    int o1 = (int)P[pc+1];
    unsigned int o2 = (unsigned)P[pc+2];
    int offset =(o1<<8) | o2;
    pc = pc + (int)offset;
    break;
}
```

Now about the code:
`P[pc+x]` will give a `1` byte integer.
And basically at the end of this, I want to set `pc` to a signed `4` byte `int`. It's not doing that however. What it is doing is taking the `1` byte, shifting it over, then taking the second byte and then bitwise or, and simply adding it. It is not taking into account the sign of o1. So, if `P[pc+1] = FF`, and `P[pc+2] = E1`, what is happening is `offset = 0000FFE1`. What I want however, is `offset = FFFFFFE1`. Basically, the first `2` bytes should take the sign of `P[pc+1]`. But this is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you also show type of array P?

Maybe adding casts as following could help:
    int o1 = (int)(int8_t)P[pc+1];
    unsigned int o2 = (unsigned)(uint8_t)P[pc+2];
    int offset = (int)((o1<<8) | o2);

If I remember correctly char might be signed or unsigned in different compilers.

Comment: Please post the declarations of `P` and `pc`, as well as the definition of `INT()`.

Comment: Oops, INT() isn't suppose to be there, pretend its not there. And P is a byte array, and pc is a way to access its index.

Comment: if it's not supposed to be there, edit it out. Edit in all the declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out if this makes sense for you:
    #include

```
int main(void) {
  short pc1= 0xFF;
  short pc2= 0xE1;
  int pc = 0;

  unsigned int highbits = 0xFFFFFFFF;

  // Check for sign bit, if true OR with highbits
  // to set all remaining bits to high
  int o1 = pc1 & 0xF0 ? pc1 | highbits : pc1;
  int offset = (int)( (o1<<8) | pc2 );
  pc = pc + (int)offset;
  printf("\npc1=%x pc2=%x pc=%x", pc1, pc2, pc);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
pc1=ff pc2=e1 pc=ffffffe1
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the declaration of P, but when you say it's a byte array, I'm assuming the specific type it has is unsigned char.

If it were signed, the cast would behave the way you wanted, because, for instance, a -1 char would become -1 int, the sign bit shifted and the remaining bits inverted as required. But when you cast from unsigned char to signed int the result will always be a positive int.

So, to solve the problem, one way is to cast the pointer/array before dereferencing it, and it'll give the desired result:

```
int o1 = (int)(((char *)P)[pc+1]);
```

One other thing: a bit shift won't work well with signed values, because it'll simply shift away the sign bit. It would work in your example, because you have 0xFF, but if you had 0x80 it'd be 0x80000000 as int, and become 0x00000000 after the shift.

So, instead of an 8-bit shift, do a multiplication:

```
int offset =(int)( (o1 * 256) + o2 );
```

Comment: Very interesting, can you explain a little more about how that casting of Char* works?

Comment: Well, basically you're saying to the compiler "look at this array as if it contained signed chars, and behave accordingly". So if P[pc+1] contains 0xFF, the cast makes it to be 'seen' as -1. This ensures that the promotion to int only happens AFTER that value was taken. If you simply do a cast of the result of P[pc+1], the compiler will have gotten (an unsigned char) 255 BEFORE the cast, and will give (at least) a warning saying the cast is losing significant digits; it doesn't know that the higher bit was originally meant to be the sign. Casting the pointer is saying that to him.

Answer (score 0):

You should check how your compiler perform Unsigned-signed and vice versa castings in C.
If i remember right (sorry if im wrong),once you have at least one UNSIGNED variable in a operation like A = B (where A receives the value of B), the compiler will deal with both values as UNSIGNED Values.

This is probably messing with your code.
Let me know the answer one way or another,i will comment here if i figure out why this happens

Comment: Ya, I think you are right. I had to do a really hacky solution. I basically made everything into short ints and it worked out.